# Keep a relation map in Objection.js while removing the table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, orm, objection.js

I'm developing a reddit-like site where votes are stored per-user (instead of per-post). Here's my relevant schema:

- **content**

  ```
  id | author_id | title       | text
  ---|-----------|-------------|---
  1  | 1 (adam)  | First Post  | This is a test post by adam
  ```
- **vote**: All the votes ever voted by anyone on any post

  ```
  id | voter_id    | content_id       | category_id
  ---|-------------|------------------|------------
  1  | 1 (adam)    | 1 ("First Post") | 1 (upvote)
  2  | 2 (bob)     | 1 ("First Post") | 1 (upvote)
  ```
- **vote_count**: Current tally ("count") of total votes received by a post by all users

  ```
  id | content_id       | category_id  | count
  ---|------------------|--------------|-------
  1  | 1 ("First Post") | 1 (upvote)   | 2
  ```

I've defined a `voteCount` [relation](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/relations.html) in [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/relations.html) model for the `content` table:

```js
class Content extends Model {  
  static tableName = 'content';
  static relationMappings = {
    voteCount: {
      relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
      modelClass: VoteCount,
      join: {
        from: 'content.id',
        to: 'vote_count.content_id'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I recently (learned and) decided that I don't need to keep (and update) a separate `vote_count` table, when in fact I can just query the `vote` table and essentially get the same table as a result:

```sql
SELECT content_id
     , category_id
     , COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM vote
GROUP 
    BY content_id
     , category_id
```

So now I wanna get rid of the `vote_count` table entirely.

But it seems that would break my `voteCount` relation since there won't be a `VoteCount` model (not shown here but it's the corresponding the model for the `vote_count` table) no more either. (Right?)

How do I keep `voteCount` relation while getting rid of `vote_count` table (and thus `VoteCount` model with it)?

Is there a way to somehow specify in the relation that instead of looking at a concrete table, it should look at the result of a query? Or is it possible to define a model class for the same?

My underlying database in PostgreSQL if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community, can't notice during review stage that you question has pretty nice formatting for a new user! (Seems your have read this already: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) So if someone will help you with your problem, don't forget to upvote sugested answer and mark question as answered. Or press `thank you` button at least.

Comment: Should be ok however I  do not know about your ORM. But "the result of a query" is a VIEW in the database. [From the Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) : A "view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Belayer. Views were exactly the solution to this problem.

Objection.js [supports](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/245#issuecomment-259978011) using views (instead of table) in a Model class, so all I had to do was create a view based on the above query.

I'm also using Knex's [migration](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-migrations) strategy to create/version my database, and although it [doesn't (yet) support](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1626#issuecomment-322412315) creating views out of the box, I found you can just use raw queries:

```js
module.exports.up = async function(knex) {
  await knex.raw(`
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "vote_count" AS (
      SELECT content_id
          , category_id
          , COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM vote
      GROUP
          BY content_id
          , category_id
    )
  `);
};
module.exports.down = async function(knex) {
    await knex.raw('DROP VIEW "vote_count";');
};
```

The above migration step replaces my table `vote_count` for the equivalent view, and the Objection.js Model class for it (`VoteCount`) worked as usual without needing any change, and so did the relation `voteCount` on the `Content` class.